# Exporting Listview items to CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, listview

i have a list view with 5 columns that i need to export to a CSV.

[image]

This is what it looks like. I looked around and couldn't find a workable solution for my problem.

This is how i am adding data into the listview:

```
$searcher = [adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$Content)"
foreach ($DirectReportDN in $searcher.FindAll().Properties.directreports)
{
    $DirectReport = [adsi]"LDAP://$DirectReportDN"
    $Username = $DirectReport.Properties.samaccountname
    $Associate = $DirectReport.Properties.name
    $Title = $DirectReport.Properties.title
    $Mgr = $DirectReport.Properties.extensionattribute6
    $Dept = $DirectReport.Properties.department

    Add-ListViewItem -ListView $listview2 -Items $Username -Group $listview2.Groups[0] -SubItems "$Associate", "$Title", "$Mgr", "$Dept"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, i have been working on this for awhile. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Exporting the items as CSV:

```
$ListViewName.Items | Export-CSV -Path "some\path.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that just puts a bunch of information about the list view in there. Such as back color, bounds, imagekey, etc. I am needing the columns and rows in there.

Comment: Zach - your answer is shit.. sorry mate.  I will get back with the correct answer